# What is popular choice for modelling distribution of orthogonal matrices

Tags: bayesian, posterior, random-matrix

In Bayesian statistics, instead of considering a variable to be fixed and use MLE to infer that value, we put a prior distribution over that variable. Now consider an orthogonal matrix $W \in R^{d \times p}; d >p$. All entries are random variables. Is there any popular distribution in literature to model the distribution of $W$ ?

My first try here is to model distribution of general matrices $A \in R^{p \times d} $ and then show some relationship between W and A.

I want to put a prior over $W$ and use some likelihood function over $W$ to find a posteior distribution over $W$.

Comment: The n by n orthogonal matrices are a compact lie group, and hence have a bi-invariant haar measure.  This is, more or less, a uniform distribution over all the n by n orthogonal matrices.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_group

Comment: Peter Hoff has some relevant work: see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.4166.